# python readin date and time in xls workbook

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xls, xlsxwriter

I have two lists that look like this (both have the same length):

```
date_list = [datetime.date(2019, 12, 2), datetime.date(2019,12,05), datetime.date(2019,12,04), datetime.date(2019,12,06)]
time_list = [datetime.time(10, 11, 55), datetime.time(10, 42, 46), datetime.time(10, 11, 45), datetime.time(10, 20, 15)]
```

Now i would like to put these two lists into a xls workbook to look like this:

[image: Excel_ouput]

I tried this code:

```
workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

date_1 = 0
for i in range(len(date_list)):
    date +=1
    Report_Sheet.write_row(0, date_1, date_list)
time_1 = 0
for i in range(len(time_list)):
    time_1 +=1
    Report_Sheet.write_row(1, time_1, time_list)
workbook.close()
```

The Problem is, that the code overwrites the cells in xls. I don't get the list element out of it. Instead it writes for every `i` the whole list.

I tried things like:

```
date_1 = 0
for i in range(len(date_list)):
    date +=1
    Report_Sheet.write_row(0, date_1, date_list[i])
```

but it doesnt work. Error shows:

TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable

Maybe someone has got a solution..
Thanks for help ;-)

Comment: In your code, you are using `date` and `time` as variables. As a best practice, one should avoid using the builtin types as variables. Please rename these to something else e.g. `date_entries` and `time_entries` and then try to get index on that.

Comment: I tried. same error..

Comment: Which xlsx module are you using? I'd like to check its docs.

Comment: this:import xlsxwriter

Comment: I don't have `xlsxwriter` handy to test, but I think you don't use a for loop at all. Just `Report_Sheet.write_row(0, 0, date_list)`. In your loop, you keep overwriting the row you just wrote. I'm not sure how date conversions work with `write_row`, you may want to keep your loop and do `write_datetime(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing full rows. By putting that in a for loop, you end up rewriting and overlapping data you've already put down.

```
workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
Report_Sheet.write_row(0, 0, date_list)
Report_Sheet.write_row(1, 0, time_list)
workbook.close()
```

`write_row` is just a helper for writing contiguous rows. If you want spaces, call one of the single cell writers

```
workbook = Workbook('output.xlsx')
Report_Sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i, d in enumerate(date_list):
    Report_Sheet.write(0, i*3, d)
for i, t in enumerate(time_list):
    Report_Sheet.write(1, i*3, t)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason why i put it in a for loop is, that i would like to have 2 column space between every date and time. i can do it with a run variable date+= 2